# Install oracle client and set path in dataflow worker

Tags: linux, python, google-cloud-platform

using the setup.py file i give custome commands like

```
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
    ['sudo','apt-get', 'update'],
    ['sudo','mkdir','-p','/opt/oracle'],
    ['sudo','apt-get','--assume-yes','install','unzip'],
    ['wget','https://storage.googleapis.com/facbeambucketv1/files/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip'],
    ['sudo','unzip','-o', 'instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip', '-d' ,'/opt/oracle'],
    ['sudo','unzip','-o', 'instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip'],
    ['sudo','apt-get','--assume-yes','install','libaio1'],
    ['sudo', 'touch', '/etc/environment'],
    ['export', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3']
]
```

everything works apart from the last line which gives an error directory now found...To confirm I had used the tree command earlier and the directory exists /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3

Comment: To set variable in subshell is nonsense as variables can't go to the parent one. Better add this in `.bash_profile` and/or `.bashrc`

Comment: tried that too gives a file not found error